# How to get shared preferences in a class that extends ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

i have an ArrayAdapter and i need to get the shared preferences of the app in order to do something with it. my problem i cant get the shared preferences.
thats my code:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private static SharedPreferences prefs;
private String firstBtName = "";
private String secondBtName = "";
private String thirdBtName = "";


public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0); // ERROR **************

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
```

eclips says that i dont have that cind of method...
What can i do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your error is because ArrayAdapter doesn't have a `getSharedPreferences()` method, Change the line that is giving you the error to this:

```
prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
```

Comment: my life is saved.

Answer (score 0):

you should get shared preferences in your constructor. your constructor should be like below

```
public MobileArrayAdapter(Context aplicationContext, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    prefs= aplicationContext.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
}
```